# Complete project package

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have been working on a D8 project and been wondering what the best course of action would be in order to produce a complete project package that can be easily set up in a new drupal installation. The theme part is pretty straightforward but what about all the specific content types that accompany a project with a specific theme? Is there a way I can have those being created on theme installation?

Comment: Am not sure if I understand you correctly: are you looking for a deployment solution, or a generic project initialization, which can be easy customized for further projects? (which are similar)

Comment: consider this scenario, you develop a theme locally which is intended for a specific project so many of your templates are specific to content types or views that you have created. Then you have to install that theme on a production server accompanied by the custom content types and so on. I've seen for example a similar functionality with wordpress where you can define custom post types on a theme's functions.php file. Anything similar?

Comment: Related: [How do I export my site structure?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/180260/1908)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for is to use [Configuration import/export](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration).

> Exporting and importing configuration changes between a Drupal installation in different environments, such as Development, Staging, and Production, allows you to make and verify your changes with a comfortable distance from your site's live environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the needed configuration files of the content types and fields needed for the site in a folder named config/install in your theme directory. These configuration gets imported when we install it.

for eg: if you want to create a content type test when your theme is installed

**Create a file node.type.test.yml in your_theme/config/install folder paste the code in it**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - menu_ui
third_party_settings:
  menu_ui:
    available_menus:
      - main
    parent: 'main:'
name: test
type: test
description: ''
help: ''
new_revision: true
preview_mode: 1
display_submitted: true
```

**Easy method is to**

- create the content types and fields form backend
- export the configuration
- Take the newly created files from it and remove the line uuid from it
- paste it in your theme folder