# Strategy for Import/exporting Drupal8 as content and structure

Tags: database, files, importing-exporting

We are setting up feature>dev>production environments on Platform.sh for a Drupal 8 project. Expecting multiple contributors to the project, we have run into a slight snag regarding Importing/Exporting custom blocks. See [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2756331) for more info about the issue.

See [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171236/configuration-export-import-not-working-for-taxonomy-terms-in-drupal-8) as well for a different but similar issue.

In our previous D7 site, we used scripts to rsync files and drop/import databases via ssh which was super easy and reliable. I know there were lots of other ways to sync which (at that time) added a layer of complexity and potential points of failure that in our opinion made sense for some, just not for us. The concept of intentionally managing separate content and structure strategies is obviously becoming standard practice so we are being urged to deal with it.

Platform.sh documentation states that the easiest way to keep things in sync is through drush sync and aliases. However, this feels like what we were doing for D7 and the point is to move away from having to drop/replace the remote database. We'd like to nail down a process at this stage that makes things easier to maintain from a project management perspective. I think most things are solved for how to get content and structure downstream so the problem really exists for how to push it all upstream without breaking things.

What strategies are typically employed for content/structure synchronization when it comes to things like this custom blocks issue?

Also, we'd be grateful if anyone has Platform.sh specific ideas to automate this step.

Answer (score 1):

As solution for site structure I use config synchronization, which is in Drupal 8 Core, and I use it with drush commands ("cex" - configuration export and "cim" - configuration import).

For content sync I don't have much experience, but I saw new module that can be interesting solution: https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync.

Comment: I saw that and structure_sync as well. Wondering what gotchas exist and hoping to spark convo around people's daily usage them.